# How to run eval in main binding

Tags: ruby, eval

How can get the main binding? In other words, in the following code, how can I make it so that `eval` ignores all the assignments, etc. previously made in `some_codes`...`some_codes`?

```
some_codes
...
some_codes
eval(string_to_be_executed, binding)
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual code? "`some_codes`" doesn't help us understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to just create a binding at the top of the file:

```
block = Proc.new{}
# some_codez
# ...
# some more of teh codez
eval(string_to_be_evaluated, block.binding)
```

Comment: Okay. That is what I was expecting. Actually, what I ended up doing was to put `$main_binding = binding` at the beginning of the file, and use that within `eval`. That seems to be slightly simpler than your code.

Comment: good point, there's no need to call binding on a Proc, since it's defined on Kernel. Thanks for teaching me about bindings, btw, they're pretty cool!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's good to know that some other people are thinking in the same line as myself so that I can understand that that way is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing this, which seems to be slightly elegant than Ben's answer which I accepted.

At the beginning of the first file to be loaded, assign something like:

```
$main_binding = binding
```

Then, when necessary, I can use it like:

```
eval(string_to_be_evaluated, $main_binding)
```